# Define extern variable of type alias in header in C

Tags: c, header-files, typedef

I have a C file that contains the following two declarations

```c
struct mmap_table_entry_t {
    uint32_t size;
    uint64_t base_addr;
    uint64_t length;
    uint8_t type;
}* mmap_table_entry;

typedef struct mmap_table_entry_t* table_entries;
```

And I want to make the type `table_entries` extern in a header file. How do I do that without declaring the whole two above types?

Comment: *I want to make the variable table_entries*. But that's not a variable. It's a `typedef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BWT hiding pointers behind the pointers is not a very good idea.

```
typedef struct mmap_table_entry_t* table_entries;
```

table_entries is not a variable only type name. It cannot be extern.

```
extern table_entries table_entries_var;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make the variable table_entries extern in a header file

If you want to declare your external var without defining the struct just do :

```
extern struct mmap_table_entry_t * table_entries;
```

If you want to define the type pointer to your struct your form `typedef struct mmap_table_entry_t* table_entries;` is valid.

A type cannot be *extern*. A *typedef* defines a type, it cannot 'force' a variable having that type to be *extern*. The type of a variable and its storage are two different things without link between them.